# How to use Javascript selectors in this situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need a code, when you hover .price-selector element (i have 4 in row), it should change color of .price element of that .price selector which is hovering. But it changes all .price element of other .price-selector boxes. In other words, I hover One thing but changes everything. How can be fixed my code?

```
$('.price-selector')
.on('mouseenter', function(){ $('.price').css({"background-color" : "red"});})
.on('mouseleave', function(){ $('.price').css({"background-color" : "black"}); });
```

Comment: Use **this** keyword or use css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted your code, so we don't know the relationship between price-selector and its price, but possibly, something like:

```
$('.price-selector')
.on('mouseenter', function(){ $(this).find('.price').css({"background-color" : "red"});})
.on('mouseleave', function(){ $(this).find('.price').css({"background-color" : "black"}); });
```

Comment: Good catch on the `.find('price')`. I missed that check.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the one who is currently being hovered, you should use `this`.

```
$('.price-selector')
    .on('mouseenter', function(){ 
        $(this).find('.price').css({"background-color" : "red"});
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function(){ 
        $(this).find('.price').css({"background-color" : "black"}); 
});
```

However, this is very inefficient. You can setup your CSS to do this for you automatically.

```
.price-selector .price {
    background-color: black;
}

.price-selector:hover .price {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: The CSS selectors might be different depending on how the HTML is structured.